# illegal component position while adding Jinternalframe

Tags: java

I am trying to run the following code but it gives me an error

```
public void addToContainer(JInternalFrame internalframe){
    JInternalFrame []allFrames = Jdpmain.getAllFrames();//getting an array of all the frames in my jdesktoppane(jdpmain)
    boolean flag=false;
    for(int i=0;i<allFrames.length;i++){
        JInternalFrame currentFrame = allFrames[i];
        if(internalframe.getClass().isInstance(allFrames[i])){
            Jdpmain.setSelectedFrame(currentFrame);//if the internal frame already exist it might be under another jinternalframe so, I called this method to bring it to focus
            flag=true;
        }
        if(flag==false){
            Jdpmain.add(internalframe); //if an instance of the frame I am adding does not exist in jdesktoppane it should add an instance of it to jdesktoppane   
        } 
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position    at
>   java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1093)   at
>   javax.swing.JLayeredPane.addImpl(JLayeredPane.java:230)   at
>   javax.swing.JDesktopPane.addImpl(JDesktopPane.java:486)   at
>   java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:410)    at
>   MyLibrarypackage.MainFrame.addToContainer(MainFrame.java:169)     at
>   MyLibrarypackage.MainFrame.jButton2ActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:148)
>     at MyLibrarypackage.MainFrame.access$100(MainFrame.java:13)     at
>   MyLibrarypackage.MainFrame$2.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:62)   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

I will be glad if anyone could help me here.

Comment: There are some issues with this code, but the most obvious is that, initially, you will never be able to add an `JInternalFrame` because the desktop does not contains any frames yet, hence the for loop does not loop at all (so, the exception can not be reproduced). Probably you wanted to move the `if(flag==false){` block behind the `for` loop. Anyway, please provide an [mcve] - you can use https://github.com/afester/CodeSamples/blob/master/Java/Swing/src/com/example/swing/MdiExample.java as a starting point.

Comment: I already have a jinternal frame in jdesktoppane which is not closable and if I move if block behind the for loop as many times the user clicks the jinternalframe add button duplicate objects of that jinternalframe will be created in the jdesktoppane. anyway, thank you so much

Comment: and my internalframes will be overlapping frames which are the same size as their parent

Comment: This is all very important information. That is the reason I asked for a [mcve]. With the code above, the issue is not reproduceable (even when trying to mock the intended behaviour with different sub classes of JInternalFrame).